# Understand what package does class belongs to by analyzing AST

Tags: dart, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to analyze AST of code (using Dart's analyzer package) and understand, what package does class `SomeClass` belongs to (was imported from).

For example, we have code and `SomeClass` is defined in uri `package:one.dart`:

```
import 'package:one.dart';
import 'two.dart';
import 'three.dart';

var x = SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
```

AST of this code is just saying that `SomeClass` is used, but gives no information about what package does this class belongs to. Should I analyze AST (build and iterate) of all imported packages and find `SomeClass` definition there?

Comment: Which API are you using? What class instance are you holding onto that holds `SomeClass`?

Comment: @KevinMoore Sorry for delay with answer. I'm pretty new to Dart's analyzer. For building AST I'm using `parseString` method from `package:analyzer/dart/analysis/utilities.dart`. But now I understand that I should take a look at Analyzer Server API. According to server API docs, there are some methods in "Search" domain that could do the trick.

Comment: @KevinMoore can you please help me a little with analysis server usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803685/how-to-use-darts-analysis-server-method-search-findtopleveldeclarations