# How to use Dart's analysis server method search.findTopLevelDeclarations?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get list of top level class declarations with Dart's analysis server. So, I'm sending `search.findTopLevelDeclarations` request, but search results are always empty.

It seems to me that analysis server **don't know where to search**. I've tried to set my project's root as execution context (`execution.createContext`) root and/or analysis root (`analysis.setAnalysisRoots`), but search results are still empty.

What should I do to make server understand where to search declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never played with this before so I got into quite a journey...

I don't know how you are interacting with the analysis server but I have made a working example using the `analysis_server_client` package. One problem doing that is that the version on pub.dev is quite old so I ended up fetching the version from the stable branch of Dart SDK:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/pkg/analysis_server_client

You can then import the package in your `pubspec.yaml` by doing:

```yaml
dependencies:
  analysis_server_client:
    path: /path/to/analysis_server_client
```

I then made a simplified version of the example code from:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/pkg/analysis_server_client/example/example.dart

```dart
import 'dart:io' show exit;

import 'package:analysis_server_client/handler/connection_handler.dart';
import 'package:analysis_server_client/handler/notification_handler.dart';
import 'package:analysis_server_client/protocol.dart';
import 'package:analysis_server_client/server.dart';

final server = Server();

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  const targetDirPath = r'C:\tmp\simple_project';
  const searchPattern = 'main';

  // Launch the server
  await server.start();

  // Connect to the server
  final handler = _Handler(server);
  server.listenToOutput(notificationProcessor: handler.handleEvent);
  if (!await handler.serverConnected(timeLimit: const Duration(seconds: 15))) {
    exit(1);
  }

  await server.send(ANALYSIS_REQUEST_SET_ANALYSIS_ROOTS,
      AnalysisSetAnalysisRootsParams([targetDirPath], const []).toJson());
  await server.send(SEARCH_REQUEST_FIND_TOP_LEVEL_DECLARATIONS,
      SearchFindTopLevelDeclarationsParams(searchPattern).toJson());
}

class _Handler with NotificationHandler, ConnectionHandler {
  @override
  final Server server;

  _Handler(this.server);

  @override
  void onSearchResults(SearchResultsParams params) {
    print('-- Start of result --');
    params.results.forEach(print);
    print('--  End of result  --');
    server.stop();
  }
}
```

The project at `C:\tmp\simple_project` is a simple project created with the following which means it just contains a single `main` method:

```
dart create -t console-simple simple_project
```

When I run my analyzer program I get the following output:

```
-- Start of result --
{"location":{"file":"C:\\tmp\\simple_project\\bin\\simple_project.dart","offset":5,"length":4,"startLine":1,"startColumn":6,"endLine":1,"endColumn":10},"kind":"DECLARATION","isPotential":false,"path":[{"kind":"FUNCTION","name":"main","location":{"file":"C:\\tmp\\simple_project\\bin\\simple_project.dart","offset":5,"length":4,"startLine":1,"startColumn":6,"endLine":1,"endColumn":10},"flags":8,"parameters":"(List<String> arguments)","returnType":"void"},{"kind":"COMPILATION_UNIT","name":"simple_project.dart","location":{"file":"C:\\tmp\\simple_project\\bin\\simple_project.dart","offset":0,"length":0,"startLine":1,"startColumn":1,"endLine":1,"endColumn":1},"flags":16},{"kind":"LIBRARY","name":"","location":{"file":"C:\\tmp\\simple_project\\bin\\simple_project.dart","offset":0,"length":0,"startLine":1,"startColumn":1,"endLine":1,"endColumn":1},"flags":0}]}
--  End of result  --
```

If I change `searchPattern` to an empty `String`, I gets a long list of top level declarations around the default included Dart SDK libraries. I am sure there are a way to exclude those.

But as far as I can see, the `searchPattern` is a regular expression tested against the name of each top level declaration and includes the declaration if its name contain any part of the regular expression.

I found the code responsible for the search here:

```dart
  @override
  Future<List<SearchMatch>> searchTopLevelDeclarations(String pattern) async {
    var allElements = <Element>{};
    var regExp = RegExp(pattern);
    var drivers = _drivers.toList();
    for (var driver in drivers) {
      var elements = await driver.search.topLevelElements(regExp);
      allElements.addAll(elements);
    }
    return allElements.map(SearchMatchImpl.forElement).toList();
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/pkg/analysis_server/lib/src/services/search/search_engine_internal.dart#L113-L123

Which calls into:

```dart
  /// Returns top-level elements with names matching the given [regExp].
  Future<List<Element>> topLevelElements(RegExp regExp) async {
    List<Element> elements = <Element>[];

    void addElement(Element element) {
      if (!element.isSynthetic && regExp.hasMatch(element.displayName)) {
        elements.add(element);
      }
    }

    List<FileState> knownFiles = _driver.fsState.knownFiles.toList();
    for (FileState file in knownFiles) {
      var unitResult = await _driver.getUnitElement(file.path);
      if (unitResult is UnitElementResult) {
        CompilationUnitElement unitElement = unitResult.element;
        unitElement.accessors.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.classes.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.enums.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.extensions.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.functions.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.mixins.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.topLevelVariables.forEach(addElement);
        unitElement.typeAliases.forEach(addElement);
      }
    }
    return elements;
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/analysis/search.dart#L166-L192

Comment: Thank you so much. I was doing exactly the same, but I had a mistake in path. Analysis server is not saying anything when analyzed directory do not exist.